# recibo dos posibles datos por url como identifico cual es

Tags: nodejs, typescript, url

**typescript**

espero tengan un buen día, tengo una api con node, express y typescript como lenguaje de programación.

Mi ruta por url recibe dos posibles datos uno con un id y otro con un numero para obtener una paginación.
El usuario puede enviar solo el id, solo la pagina, ninguno o ambos datos

como puedo identificar si es el id que mando o la pag.

`router.get('/getfriendsPag/:id?/:pag?', verificarToken, paginateFriends)`

esta es la parte del codigo que recibe los datos

```
export const paginateFriends = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let userId = req.userId; //este es un user id que recibe por un token

    if(req.params.id) { //en caso de que la url reciba un params.id el userId es remplazado por este
        userId = req.params.id;
    }

    let pag: number = 1;
    if(req.params.pag){
        pag = +req.params.pag;
    }
    console.log(userId, pag)
}
```

el problema principal es cuando solo se le envía por url la **pag** ya que se toma como el id

Comment: ¿Y como estas mandando la peticion GET? por ejemplo localhsot:3000/getfriends..

Comment: exacto mando los datos con insomnia atraves de un GET con esta ruta
http://localhost:3000/api/friends/getfriendsPag/
que puede llevar o no dos parámetros
la aplicacion es un port de una red social por ejemplo el usuario quiere ver los amigos de una persona este selecciona a la persona se manda un id por url y adicional quiere ver la pagina 2 ya que son datos paginados, se envia num de pagina igual por url. espero darme a entender. @SaulEspinoza

Comment: Los datos que envías en la url se identifican por su posición. No puedes enviar la página sin enviar el id. Para eso podrías usar parámetros GET [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997)

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoseAntonioCastro no conocía el req.query. Únicamente avia utilizado req.params